# SQL script to determine if CRM 2011 solution is being imported

Tags: sql, dynamics-crm-2011

Is there any way to determine, through SQL, if the CRM database is currently being updated as a result of a solution import?

Comment: I have no idea but I am incredibly curious as to why you would want to know * nosey *

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ImportJob view will show you information about all the solution imports that have happened in the org.

If you started the import using the SDK you can query for the job based on ID, else by whatever method you choose.

There is a Progress column that shows the percentage complete of the import, plus there is XML data in the data column that can be parsed for the status.

Comment: Where is "the ImportJob view" ? Is this in CRM? Or SSMS?

Comment: Edited answer to make more explicit.

Comment: My edit seems to have vanished (not approved?) so adding as alternative answer. See below...

Answer (score 7):

[Apologies for copying parts of Ben Williams's answer. I tried to edit his but my edit seemed not to be approved.]

The ImportJob view will show you information about all the solution imports that have happened in the org.

If you started the import using the SDK you can query for the job based on ID, else by whatever method you choose.

There is a Progress column that shows the percentage complete of the import, plus there is XML data in the data column that can be parsed for the status.

This query (from http://sachindgmits.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/sql-query-to-get-progress-of-importing.html) shows the most recent job:

```
Use <<OrgName_MSCRM>>
Go

SELECT TOP 1
    progress                                 [Progress%],
    Solutionname                             [SolutionName],
    DATEADD(hh, 5.5, startedon)              [StartedOnPST],
    DATEADD(hh, 5.5, completedon)            [CompletedOnPST],
    DATEDIFF(second,startedon,completedon)   [TimeTakenInSec],
    DATEDIFF(minute,startedon,completedon)   [TimeTakenInMin],
    createdbyname                            [ImportedBy],
    OrganizationIdName                       [OrgName],
    Data                                     [ImportOutput]
FROM
    importjob IJ (NOLOCK)
ORDER BY
    IJ.startedon DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about query but you could try using sql profiler to see if any queries are running on real time on your db..